# Nodejs Request Cheerio - Scraping website with for loop

Tags: node.js, for-loop, request, cheerio

I scraped this website https://www.alza.sk/cpu-procesory/18842843-p1.htm this is big Czecho-Slovakia e-shop with pc components, i want to fetch data about CPU.

I apologize for using the Slovak words in the code, but it doesn't matter.

// CODE

```
url = 'https://www.alza.sk/cpu-procesory/18842843-p1.htm';

var allCpu = new Array;

request(url, function(error, response, html) {
    if(error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        var $ = cheerio.load(html);
        var box = $('#boxc .box');

    for(i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
       console.log(i) // Output is numbers from 0 to 23

        var cpu = {
            meno: '',
            link: '',
            socket: '',
            radaCpu: '',
            xJadier: '',
            frekvenciaCpu: '',
            maxFrekvenciaCpu: ''
        }

        box.eq(i).filter(function() {
            cpu.meno = $(this).find('.fb a').text();
            cpu.link = $(this).find('.fb a').attr('href');

            request('https://www.alza.sk/' + cpu.link, function(error, response, html) {
                if(error) {
                    console.log(error);
                } else {
                    var $socket = cheerio.load(html);
                    var params = $socket('#popis .params .groupValues .row a');

                    params.filter(function() {
                        if($(this).text() == 'Socket') cpu.socket = $(this).parents('.row').find('.value').text();
                        if($(this).text() == 'Rad procesora') cpu.radaCpu = $(this).parents('.row').find('.value').text();
                        if($(this).text() == 'Počet jadier procesora') cpu.xJadier = $(this).parents('.row').find('.value').text();
                        if($(this).text() == 'Frekvencie procesora') cpu.frekvenciaCpu = $(this).parents('.row').find('.value').text();
                        if($(this).text() == 'Maximálna frekvencia (OC)') cpu.maxFrekvenciaCpu = $(this).parents('.row').find('.value').text();
                    });

                    allCpu.push(cpu);

                    console.log(i); // Output is 24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24

                    if(i == box.length - 1) {

                        fs.writeFile('output.json', JSON.stringify(allCpu, null, 4), function(err){
                            console.log('File successfully written! - Check your project directory for the output.json file');
                        });
                    }
                }
            });

        });

    }

  }
});
```

This code work great if i fetch data from one specific CPU. ( box.eq(some_number) ).

Firstly it execute request, find name and link to the CPU. Next it with this link execute next request, which find other detail information.

But if i use loop because i want to fetch data of all CPU on the page. I always get data only from last CPU.
I let increment write to console on start my loop and on the end. On the start of loop i had numbers from 0 to 23 it's good. But on the end in the console i got 24 times number 24. I don't understand why.

Thank you for help.

Comment: If you are looping over many items I would consider making this an asynchronous loop so that each item is dealt with before moving onto the next. I have done this many times with no impact to performance. Have a look into async await (or even better look at JS callback, promises and then async await), this will help you understand how this process has evolved. As a side note have you considered using puppeteer ? very good and supports async :-)

Comment: Hi Richlewis, i used promises in my code and all work well. Thank you, your advice very helped me.

Comment: Good to hear, glad I could help